# remove elements of an array from a group of arrays

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter

if I have this array

`const array1 = [['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'] , ['a'] , ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] , ['a' , 'c' , 'f']]`

and this array
`const array2 = ['a']`

I want to return array1 without all the elements of array2

I am using react.js

am trying to return array1 without all the elements of array2
how can I do this using react.js

Comment: array1.map(innerArray =>
    innerArray.filter(item => !array2.includes(item))
  );